# Show in Finder not working in 10.8

Tags: cocoa, nsworkspace

This works in 10.7 but not in 10.8. How do I get this to work in Mountain Lion?

```
-(IBAction)showTargetInFinder:(id)sender
{

     NSString *linkPath = [targetField stringValue];
     NSWorkspace *ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
     [ws selectFile:linkPath inFileViewerRootedAtPath:nil];

}
```

Comment: You should go with Pedro Vieira's solution, since URLs instead of paths is the way forward generally, but another thing to try (if only for curiosity's sake) would be to use the path-based method with `@""` for the file viewer root, rather than `nil`. [The documentation's explanation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/selectFile:inFileViewerRootedAtPath:) is rather archaic, but the gist is that `@""` is the more useful root value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
NSURL *fileURL = your file URL;
NSArray *fileURLs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fileURL, nil];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:fileURLs];
```

This works on 10.6+. If you want to show and select more than one file on Finder just add more `NSURLs` to the array and you're good to go.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of asking NSArray to create an array for you, use an array literal: `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:@[ fileURL ]]`

Comment: This does not work for me on 10.8.2 either. I know the path is valid, I can ls to verify. This statement does nothing: `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs: @[ [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.myPath] ]]`

Answer (score 0):

From a sanity-check point of view: If the user running the process which makes the `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:@[ fileURL ]]` call doesn't have read/view permissions for `fileURL` then the method will appear to "not work".

To determine if this is your issue (As of OS X 10.10.3), check your console for logs like the following:

```
6/18/15 10:34:46.195 AM NameOfApp[42753]: AppleEvents failed to encode extension for /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/xxxxxxxxxxx/yyyy.zzz, err=Permission denied/13
```